# Disable communication between subnets in azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template, subnet

How to disable communication between subnets in azure through PowerShell or ARM template?
There is a scenario, where i am wanting to disable communication between subnets in Azure. I understand that it can be achieved through NSG rules. Can someone throw light on this from the PowerShell or ARM template solution perspective on what sort of rules need to be set so that it disables only the communication from subnets and not accessing of resource from other sources. Any PowerShell or ARM template samples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to block traffic from the target subnet ip range and to that ip range. alternatively you can block all the vnet traffic with the `virtualnetwork` service tag.

Comment: Can you share a sample diagram and powershell or ARM template solution ?